# Use custom environment variable as "target location" for taskbar-pins and shortcuts

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, environment-variables, desktop-customization

I have created a custom environment variable with usual GUI method in my system with Windows 7 64-Bit OS.

But I cannot set it as "target location" for any of my custom taskbar pins(icons) through context menu.

This should no-doubt work as I can execute the variable from "Start" bar and "Run" box.

Can someone help out ?

Comment: Did you trying logging off and back on again?

Comment: Yes, but in vain

Comment: Not that this solves your problem, but does it work if you create a custom System variable?